# Set container view height to nib loaded subview height

Tags: ios, view, frame, autolayout

I am loading subviews from different .xib files and adding them to a container view. The problem is I can't figure out how to make the container view's height automatically adjust to the subview. When I access the `subView.frame.size.height` it comes back with a correct value. For example, 44. But when I set the height of the containerView by making a rect `containerView.frame = GCRectMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, 44)` it does not work and keeps its original height. I have also tried `[containerView sizeToFit:subView.frame.size]` to no avail.

Comment: Using auto-layout on the container view?

Comment: The subview is added programmatically so I don't know how I would set up auto layout

Comment: What about the container view though, that is what you're trying to set the frame of, no?

Comment: Yes, but I want its height to be the height of the programmatically added subview.